# How to use SUMIF when there are multiple items in one cell?

Tags: excel-formula

I have two sheets in my  sample Excel file:

Sheet1 is where I would like the SUMIFS function to sum up the number of employees associated with each company in the states that I've listed in a comma-separated list.

Sheet2 is where I've supplied the data broken up so that each row represents a company, a single state, and a number of employees.

The problem that I'm having is that I am unsure how I can break up a comma-separated listed of states so that I can use it as a criteria in my SUMIFS function.

I have tried doing this through Google Sheets using TRANSPOSE and SPLIT to create a vertical array, but that didn't work. I'm seeking help for this problem in Excel because that's where I primarily have to work in, but I am open to any ideas using GSheets.

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60JIy.png)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbiCI.png)

Comment: I suggest use find()... But you should read this and then you may get a better solution : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Why are you tagging "excel formula" when you say you are using google sheets? Do you know the difference? Use tags properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMIFS wrapped in SUMPRODUCT and TRIM(MID()) to parse the string:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(H:H,F:F,A2,G:G,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99))))
```

[image]